# Send all data from row (not only changed) during update request from ListGrid in SmartGWT

Tags: rest, smartgwt

Currently I'm trying to customize SmartGWT's DataSource to work with custom REST services. And I hit into problem with sending update requests when some changes have been made in the ListGrid row. By default only changed cells in the row are sent in update request (as described [here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Editing.html)). And I want to change this behavior to send all data from the row not just edited. I've already spent a lot of time figuring out how to do this but still can't find a solution. Could you please give me any advice how to change this OOTB behavior? Probably someone has had similar problem and found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way how I implement sending all data from the row during update request. Probably it will help someone.

I overrode *transformRequest* method and added there such code:

```
@Override
protected Object transformRequest(final DSRequest dsRequest) {
    ...
    if (dsRequest.getOperationType = OperationType.UPDATE) {
       ...
       final JavaScriptObject basicJSObject = dsRequest.getOldValues().getJsObj();
       final JavaScriptObject latestChanges = dsRequest.getData();
       JSOHelper.addProperties(basicJSObject, latestChanges);

       // Regexp probably can be optimized
       final String resultString = JSON.encode(responseData)
            .replaceAll("[,]\\s*[,]", ",")
            .replaceAll("^\\s*[,]", "")
            .replaceAll("[,]\\s*$", "");

       return resultString;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does responseData = basicJSObject?

Answer (score 1):

//Override the transformRequest function in DataSource
//

@Override

protected void transformResponse(DSResponse response, DSRequest request,
        Object data){

```
    // On Update Operation call will hit the below condition    
    //
    if (dsRequest.getOperationType().equals(DSOperationType.UPDATE)) {

        // Get the data from listGird
        //
                    listGrid.getDataAsRecordList()

                    //Set to request 
                    //
                    dsRequest.setData();

    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I meant another thing. I meant that I want to send all data from a row (not all rows) and default implementation sends only data from edited cells in the row. I've found some mistakes in my questions that probably puzzled you and fix them. And actually today I have found a solution of my problem and will post it little later.